# php://input always empty when GET

Tags: php, apache

I have a webportal (laravel code base) running on a Cloudlinux based server with PHP 7.2. 
Due to some capacity problems we need to love to another server, also Cloudlinux, but PHP 7.3.

I try now to use the new server, but that give me a problem. For some of the parts I need to call a secondary platform (same server). I use for this a GET curl.

On the old server this works perfect, on the new one however I have issues. The data that I pass in the body isn’t read by the new server. When I do a dump of all request data it is not included.
If I run the same system over POST, then somehow it is working perfect.

I know that I can change all requests to POST, but that is a big job, and why does it work then on the old server. I have the impression reading the PHP://input doesn’t work on GET, but don’t know if this is a setting or not.

Switching to another PHP version didn’t help btw

Comment: can you show us the phpini ?

Comment: Related: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061)

Comment: I know that it is better not to use (according to that link). However, changing everything will take time. Http://shorturl.at/rCE02 is the PHP info file. Easier then the PHP.ini, or is the PHP.ini better (as we use CloudLinux the PHP.ini is for every part of the portal independent.